# Adding a field to a document using upsert

Tags: meteor

I have a collection  `members` that i want to update. The document contains only a field telephonenumber and id.

I have several telephone numbers

I want to add an extra field `names` and i am using a method to do that

```
'updatenumber': function(tn,names){


  Members.update({
             telephoneNumber: tn
          }, {
             $set: {
                telephoneNumber: tn,
                names:names
             }
          }, {
              upsert: true
          });
          console.log(names);


 },
```

```

Although tn and names contain data from clientside, the field names is not added. Why is that?.

Comment: Are you sure it is not added? Did you update your publication to get it sent back? Are you using a schema?

Comment: can you show us your schema code?

Comment: There is no schema. I am not using autoform or simple schema. The error originates from autoform simple schema although there are cases where the same error shows up on non-meteor apps when using mongoose.THis is the exact error `MongoError: '$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}`

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I had indeed defined a simple schema object with only one field which telephone number and left out names which i introduced later. Although not using autoform directly,simple schema was very much active,not sure why.